# Set $E = \mathbb R \setminus \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \}$ is Open in $\mathbb R$ ? Is it Closed in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Set $E = \mathbb R \setminus \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \}$ is Open in $\mathbb R$ ? Is it Closed in $\mathbb R$?

We can find it directly from taking complement of set. Complement would be $ E' = \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \} $

Complement would not be Open because there won't be any interior points. Complement would not be Closed because it doesn't contain limit point $0$. So we can say that set $E$ is closed and open from complement method.

Now check it without taking complement.

Set E won't be open because $0$ won't be interior point.

Set E won't be closed because it doesn't contain many limit points. E.g. $1$ is limit point of sequence $\{ 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ $ |  $  $ n \in \mathbb N \}$.

Why I am getting different answers ?

Edit:
I interpreted theorem incorrectly. Theorem is:

> Set is closed if and only if its complement is open.

So above complement is neither closed nor open, we can't say that set $E$ is open and closed.

Comment: The complement of a set which is neither open nor closed is also neither open nor closed. eg.$\left[0,1\right)$. "$A$ is not open" is equivalent to "$A'$ is not closed".

Comment: Ohh I got it. Thanks. I interpreted theorem incorrectly.